# Chart.js not show in my function (function used in ajax) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) for charting.
I used Jquery 3.3.1 and get the data from an Ajax.
In my HTML code I added a canvas already.
My HTML is:

```
<div style="width:90%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

I've tried copy the code to place at html tag `<script></script>` in the bottom of the body, the chart is show...but I don't what that because I can't use my array that in ajax.

My Code :

$('#frm-report').submit(function (e) {

```
e.preventDefault();
var month = $('#month')[0].value;
var syear = $('#startyear')[0].value;
var eyear = $('#endyear')[0].value;
var top = $('#top')[0].value;
var comp = $("input[name='compare']:checked").val();

if (comp == 'to') {
    if (syear == eyear) {
        alert("Last Year : Please choose less than the first year.");
    } else {
        toajax(month, syear, eyear, top, comp);
    }
} else if (comp == 'between') {
    toajax(month, syear, eyear, top, comp);
}
```

});

function toajax(month,syear,eyear,top,comp){

```
var arrlabel = [];
var arrt1 = [];
var arrt2 = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'report.php',
    data: {
        matem: true,
        month: month,
        syear: syear,
        eyear: eyear,
        top: top,
        comp: comp
    },
    success: function (data) {

        var dt = $.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(dt,function (i,v) {
            var arrcat = [];       
            arrcat.push(v.category);       
            arrcat.push(v.ttl1, v.ttl2);
            arrt1.push(v.ttl1);
            arrt2.push(v.ttl2);
            arrcat.push(v.p);
            arrav.push(v.p);

            arrlabel.push(arrcat);             
        });

        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: arrlabel,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: arrt1
                }, {
                    label: 'My Second dataset',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: arrt2,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart with Multiline Labels'
                },
            }
        };
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
        };
    }
});
```

}

I expect the Chart is show and can use array that from ajax. 
But the chart not show any data. 
What wrong?
How can I do to make the chart is show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are creating the chart only one time when window load in order to update chart you need to create it again for doing that you should remove window.onload() after doin this your success function should look like this

```
    success: function (data) {

    var dt = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(dt,function (i,v) {
        var arrcat = [];       
        arrcat.push(v.category);       
        arrcat.push(v.ttl1, v.ttl2);
        arrt1.push(v.ttl1);
        arrt2.push(v.ttl2);
        arrcat.push(v.p);
        arrav.push(v.p);

        arrlabel.push(arrcat);             
    });

    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: arrlabel,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: arrt1
            }, {
                label: 'My Second dataset',
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: arrt2,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart with Multiline Labels'
            },
        }
    };

        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);

}
```

Let me know if you need more help